# Excel calculating interest rate on loan

Tags: loans, calculation, spreadsheet

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this type of question, apologies if it isn't.

I am following [**this**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Goal-Seek-to-find-the-result-you-want-by-adjusting-an-input-value-320cb99e-f4a4-417f-b1c3-4f369d6e66c7) explanation on office support to answer my own question.

Using the values they use, what would I change if payments were made at the beginning of each month, if any? Also, is the interest rate calculated the monthly or annual rate?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Please include in the question the key parts of the linked web page, otherwise the question will be worthless if the link rots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution uses the [PMT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PMT-function-0214da64-9a63-4996-bc20-214433fa6441) which has the syntax:

```
PMT(rate, nper, pv, [fv], [type])
```

where

Fv is Optional: The future value, or a cash balance you want to attain after the last payment is made. If fv is omitted, it is assumed to be 0 (zero), that is, the future value of a loan is 0.

and

Type is Optional: The number 0 (zero) or 1 and indicates when payments are due.

```
0 or omitted: At the end of the period
1: At the beginning of the period
```

So `PMT(0.0058508,180,100000) = -900`

or `PMT(0.0058508,180,100000,0,0) = -900` both paying at the end of the period.

The periodic (monthly) interest rate is `0.0058508 = 0.0702095 / 12`

For the calculation with payments at the beginning of the period use

```
=PMT(B3/12,B2,B1,0,1)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!   Probably should have looked closer, when I did the =PMT(B3/12,B2,B1,0,1) it showed me what the 0 and 1 represented